# Is possible to do faster filter-IN queries?

Tags: query-optimization, sparql, wikidata

This query seems very lazy for a "WHERE IN"... Because not need to check "the universe", only the little `IN ()` set.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?of ?ofLabel
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 ?of.
  FILTER ( ?item IN (
    wd:Q28114532, wd:Q27745011,wd:Q3415363,wd:Q3415324,wd:Q2877432,wd:Q2877444,
    wd:Q2396644,wd:Q3444776,wd:Q2877428,wd:Q578757,wd:Q2877445,wd:Q2333617
  ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

**There are another way to do faster the same thing?**

---

NOTE

The problem grows with similar thing, but checking if the item has "any dependency" —  an instance, sub-instance, class or sub-class of something (eg. Q7860962).

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?x ?xLabel
WHERE 
{
  ?x (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)* wd:Q7860962 .
  ?item wdt:P31 ?x .
  FILTER ( ?item IN (
    wd:Q28114532, wd:Q27745011,wd:Q3415363,wd:Q3415324,wd:Q2877432,wd:Q2877444,
    wd:Q2396644,wd:Q3444776,wd:Q2877428,wd:Q578757,wd:Q2877445,wd:Q2333617
  ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

Comment: in this simple query there is no room for optimization. I mean, it's just a single triple pattern + a filter. the alternative is using *inline data* by means of SPARQL `VALUES` clause: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?of ?ofLabel
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 ?of.
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q28114532 wd:Q27745011 wd:Q3415363 wd:Q3415324 wd:Q2877432 wd:Q2877444
    wd:Q2396644 wd:Q3444776 wd:Q2877428 wd:Q578757 wd:Q2877445 wd:Q2333617
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AKSW has pointed out, you could use [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data). Your first query will be ~150 times faster:

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?of ?ofLabel
WHERE 
{ VALUES (?item) {
      (wd:Q28114532) (wd:Q27745011) (wd:Q3415363) (wd:Q3415324) (wd:Q2877432) (wd:Q2877444)
      (wd:Q2396644)  (wd:Q3444776)  (wd:Q2877428) (wd:Q578757)  (wd:Q2877445) (wd:Q2333617)
  }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?of.
  SERVICE wikibase:label  { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fof%20%3FofLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%28wd%3AQ28114532%29%20%28wd%3AQ27745011%29%20%28wd%3AQ3415363%29%20%28wd%3AQ3415324%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877432%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877444%29%0A%20%20%28wd%3AQ2396644%29%20%28wd%3AQ3444776%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877428%29%20%28wd%3AQ578757%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877445%29%20%28wd%3AQ2333617%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fof.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

In your second query, you should also add [`hint:Prior hint:gearing "forward"`](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints):

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?x ?xLabel
WHERE 
{
  VALUES (?item) {
      (wd:Q28114532) (wd:Q27745011) (wd:Q3415363) (wd:Q3415324) (wd:Q2877432) (wd:Q2877444)
      (wd:Q2396644)  (wd:Q3444776)  (wd:Q2877428) (wd:Q578757)  (wd:Q2877445) (wd:Q2333617)
  }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?x .
  ?x (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)* wd:Q7860962 .
  hint:Prior hint:gearing "forward" .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fx%20%3FxLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%28wd%3AQ28114532%29%20%28wd%3AQ27745011%29%20%28wd%3AQ3415363%29%20%28wd%3AQ3415324%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877432%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877444%29%0A%20%20%28wd%3AQ2396644%29%20%28wd%3AQ3444776%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877428%29%20%28wd%3AQ578757%29%20%28wd%3AQ2877445%29%20%28wd%3AQ2333617%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fx%20.%0A%20%20%3Fx%20%28wdt%3AP31%7Cwdt%3AP279%29%2a%20wd%3AQ7860962%20.%0A%20%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3Agearing%20%22forward%22%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)